# how nicely solve selenium promise? protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, protractor, pageobjects

I wrote the following code (page object pattern). Works correctly.
However, I don't like this, because I can't remove "then" from "pressHelpLink". Instead add the code in getElementByLink.

I would like to see ElementFinder Promise (instead of ManagedPromise) as result of getElementByLink("Help")

How nicely solve selenium promise?

```
var self = Page.create({
    url: {value: ''},

    // function:
    getElementByLink: {
        value: function (link) {
            return element.all(by.repeater('items')).then(function (el) {
                var my_array = el.map(function (el) {
                    return el.element(self.by.xpath('a'));
                });
                var element_array_finder = protractor.ElementArrayFinder.fromArray(my_array);

                var element = element_array_finder.filter(function (el) {
                    return el.getText().then(function (text) {
                        return text === link;
                    })
                });
                return element;
            }).then(function (element) {
                world.expect(element.length).equal(1);
                return element[0];
            });
        }

    },

    // elements:
    HelpLink: {
        get: function () {
            return self.getElementByLink('Help');
        }
    },

    // method:

    pressHelpLink: {
        value: function () {
            return self.HelpLink.then(function (el) {
                return el.click()
            });
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `cssContainingText`? Maybe something like...

```
// elements:
HelpLink: {
    get: function () {
        return element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Help');
    }
},

// method:

pressHelpLink: {
    value: function () {
        return self.HelpLink.click()
    }
},
```

Comment: With this method, I can shorten the code. But on the site can occur several such elements.